# No Dummy Accounts Generated With Firebase Auth Emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

Hi I am running firebase node project locally with Firestore, Functions and Auth emulators. When I try signing in with popup I get an empty popup with no dummy login. Please find image and code below. I don't understand with there is no dummy data. Works perfectly fine when connecting to production environment. Please can anyone explain why I don't see any accounts?

```js
// Get a Firestore instance
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099/");
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}
```

Clicking on add new account does nothing.
[image]

Node service

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you might be doing something wrong here
would recommend going through this article and hope you find a work around.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. What accounts are you expecting to see in that popin? If you want to see the accounts you created using the SDK (client or admin), you need to go to the emulator UI, available by default on localhost:4000 and then check the Auth tab.[image]

The popin in your screenie is only there to generate federated accounts.

Comment: According to the documentation there should be Mock accounts when calling the signInWithPopup SDK function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#testing_firebase_sdk-driven_idp_flows
"The emulator creates mock third-party user accounts and credentials as needed as the flows proceed."

Comment: I think you are misreading this. The popin will help you generate mock data once you click on the "Add new account", but there won't be anything there by default.  Once generated, the mock accounts will be added to the Emulator Auth service and available under localhost:4000/auth.

Comment: That one of the problems I am facing, clicking “Add new account” does nothing. All other Auth related functionality is working as expected using the Auth emulator.

Comment: Right. I am with you now. When I ran into problems with the Auth emulator previously that was either because the ports / path defined in my code did not match the actual assigned ports, or the service worker was messing with me on my local dev. Might not seem like much but can you try removing the final "/" you have there: connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099/"). The docs do without: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#instrumentauth