# Firebase Auth Emulator keeps suggesting real Google accounts

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, firebaseui, firebase-tools

**TL;DR**
Firebase Auth Emulator keeps suggesting real Google accounts.
One in a hundred attempts result in an emulator dummy account popup.

**DETAILED**

*firebase providers setup:*

```
importProvidersFrom(
      provideAuth(() => {
        const auth = getAuth();
        if (environment.useEmulators) {
          connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099');
        }
        return auth;
      }),
```

*clicking on 'login':*

```
<button (click)="onLoginButtonClicked()>login</button>
onLoginButtonClicked() {
this.matDialog.open(FirebaseUiComponent)...
```

[image: login-button]

*triggers FirebaseUI modal':*
[image: firebaseui-modal]

```
import fbc_app from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { AngularFireAuth as Afc_Auth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import * as fbui from 'firebaseui';


export class FirebaseUiComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  afc_Auth = inject(Afc_Auth);
  dialogRef = inject(MatDialogRef<FirebaseUiComponent>);

  ui!: fbui.auth.AuthUI;

  uiConfig = {
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: (authResult) => this.dialogRef.close(authResult),
      signInFailure: (error) => this.dialogRef.close(error),
    },
    signInOptions: [fbc_app.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID],
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    // ...
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afc_Auth.app.then(app => {
      this.ui = new fbui.auth.AuthUI(app.auth());
      this.ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', this.uiConfig);
      this.ui.disableAutoSignIn();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { this.ui.delete(); }
}
```

*after clicking on 'Sign in with Google' a modal with a 'dummy' account, or an 'add new account' button should show:*

[image: modal-with-dummy-account]

*...instead I'm getting a popup with my 'real' Google accounts to select from:*

[image: modal-with-real-accounts]

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "suggesting real Google accounts".  I don't know what it means for the Emulator to "suggest" something?  I don't know what "real Google accounts" are?  I don't know what "an emulator dummy account popup" means?

Comment: Hi @GregFenton, I've just asked the same question on Firebase Slack. Anyways, the 'real accounts' are my Google accounts (one personal, the other is for work) that I use to send emails and to authenticate myself with many services (stackoverflow, etc.).

Comment: Please edit the question to be more clear what you're observing. I also have no idea what "real accounts" are and how they differ from "dummy accounts", or what it means to get a "suggestion".  Your question should contain enough information that someone can use to duplicate your observations.  Please list out your instructions clearly.  Maybe a screenshot would help, or copied textual output.

Comment: I've just updated my question. If there's anything else I should add, let me know, please.

Comment: How did you get to that login button? What exactly are you logging in to?  It doesn't follow from the code you've shown.  The code just configures a web application to use an emulator as the source of Firebase user accounts for that app.  There's still not enough instruction here that someone could follow to reproduce this on their own.  The screen that lets you choose an account looks like a generic google account picker that selects from accounts that you previously used in the browser.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added some code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to removing multiple dependencies from the project and adding them back one by one.

Turns out that the culprit was the **"firebaseui"** package. After removing this package (switching it for my custom login component), the emulators started working fine.

When we click 'login'

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithPopup } from '@angular/fire/auth';
signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => { ...
```

> **IF the auth-emulator IS NOT running/connected**, we get the standard
> Google accounts selector with the list of Google accounts that were
> used to sign in previously using that browser.

> **IF the auth-emulator IS running/connected**, we get the emulator
> account selector (auth-emulator-login-widget) with "dummy"/"fake" accounts stored in the emulator
> (if previously created). There's also a **"+ Add new account"** button
> to create new "dummy"/"fake" accounts if necessary.

[image: auth-emulator-login-widget]

I hope this answer will help someone facing this issue and save them some time.

Comment: This is just another reason to not use the Firebase UI - it should be banned

Answer (score 0):

The list of Google accounts you're looking at is generated by Google based on the accounts you previously used to sign in to the site, using the current browser. Google doesn't know or care which ones might be "real" or "dummy" - they are all just accounts to show.  The only control you have over that list is to fully sign out of the accounts you don't want to see.

If you don't want them all listed in the same place, you could try using a different browser (or different browser profiles) for your different types of accounts to keep them separate.  The list of signed-in accounts will not follow you from browser to browser.

Comment: should also clarify the difference between a html popup vs a window popup as the names are interchangeable but are functionally different.

Comment: @DougStevenson Shouldn't the running emulator somehow "intercept" this process? As I mentioned earlier, one in every x attempts results in it working, and I'm presented with the emulator login popup, even though I'm not signed out of any of my accounts.

Comment: This process relies on an Auth provider, in this case, Google. The Auth window from Google loads all linked users to authenticate and is not managed within your app. if you have a dummy user that is also a google account, you must authenticate within google to identify as that user. such as logging in through Gmail.com. this window is not associate with your app or firebase at all and cannot be manipulated for security reasons.

Comment: @DIGIByte Test users exist in the emulated auth database only when I place them there, and I can't achieve this without the emulator's auth window appearing. While the user is not in the emulated auth database, I cannot authenticate as that user. On certain occasions, the authentication emulator accurately "intercepts" the authentication action (triggered by clicking on the 'Sign In with Google' FirebaseUI widget button), leading to the correct popup. As if the emulator successfully performs the "intercept" at times and fails to do so at other times.

Comment: There is no direct link between the emulator and the account selector.  The account selector is driven by the browser (not the emulator) and handled on Google backends (again, not the emulator). You can see this account selector being used on all Google web properties.  The emulator just receives a token after the user is signed in so that it knows about the account.

Comment: (1/2) Doug, when the auth emulator is running, it provides (as it should) its own account selector. There is an image within this question showing this emulator-account-selector. We can see the "Sign-in with Provider" and "Please select an existing account in the Auth Emulator or add a new one" and the "+ Add new account" button. In this emulator-account-selector we would see all the "dummy"/"fake" accounts created via this emulator-account-selector. If there is no "dummy"/"fake" account, we can create one and use it in our emulator, without having to authenticate with our "real" Google acc.

Comment: (2/2) The issue I'm experiencing is that the emulator-account-selector does not pop up after I click login (even though the auth emulator is running). It goes straight to the "real" google-account-selector, which means I can't create any "dummy"/"fake" users for my emulator.

Comment: The list of auth accounts you see in the emulator is not directly related to the authentication dialog provided by Google.  Again, the auth dialog from Google **only** uses the google accounts you have previously used to sign in to your app using that browser, regardless of whether or not your app is connected to an emulator or the actual cloud service. Changing the list of accounts known by the emulator is never going to impact what Google renders for that auth dialog.

Comment: (1/2) @DougStevenson I've never stated that "the list of auth accounts ... in the emulator is related to the authentication dialog provided by Google." I'm saying that IF the auth emulator IS NOT running/connected, I should see, as you wrote, "Google accounts ... previously used to sign in ... using that browser." IF, however, the emulator IS running/connected, I SHOULD NOT SEE the "Google accounts ... previously used to sign in ... using that browser." Instead, I should see the emulator account selector with "dummy"/"fake" accounts that are stored in the emulator (if previously created).

Comment: (2/2) This Stack Overflow question contains an image of the "emulator-account-selector":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145088/no-dummy-accounts-generated-with-firebase-auth-emulator

There is a heading "Sign-in with Provider"
It also says "Please select an existing account in the Auth Emulator or add a new one:" Which means this popup gets its content (accounts) from the running auth emulator instance.
And a button to create a new "dummy"/"fake" account in the emulator.

Comment: It sounds like you know what the behavior of the emulator should be, and it's not working the way you expect.  In that case, file a bug on the [firebase-tools GH](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) with your repro instructions. The volunteers on Stack Overflow can't really help with this.